# Consistency with abstraction functions

Tags: c++, stack, abstraction

I have the following function that I use multiple times in my class for abstraction:

```
void Interpreter::pushToStack(int value)
{
    stack.push_back(std::to_string(value));
}
```

Now I have a certain function where I do this:

```
stack.push_back(stack.back());
```

Is this bad practice? Is it bad to not be consistent in using abstraction functions? Because I think I can't really use `pushToStack(int)` since it requires an integer and I want to push `stack.back()`.

Thanks!

Comment: you can call the function like this `pushToStack(std:stoi(stack.back()))`

Comment: Yeah, I though about that but is that necessarily better code? Or is `stack.pus_back(stack.back());` 'good' code too?

Comment: This is opinion-based but I would say that this design is bad. There should be a single unified way of mutating a data member. Having both, `pushToStack()` member function and occasional bare `push_back`s, is very confusing.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that this is indeed a bit opinion-based, but I think I agree with you. I'll use my `pushToStack(int)`-function consistent!

Comment: You could make it virtual, and overwrite it if needed in the "Child" class

Answer (score 1):

For consistency, you could add an overload for strings,

```
void Interpreter::pushToStack(int value)
{
    stack.push_back(std::to_string(value));
}

void Interpreter::pushToStack(std::string value)
{
    stack.push_back(value);
}
```

and then at all the call points you'd use the same approach

```
pushToStack(5);
pushToStack(stack.back());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this input. I'd like to know if more people think this is even a better solution.

Comment: @TristanvO I guess this is a worse solution. I don't like the splitting of `stack` between the call point and the function body. Something like `void Interpreter::duplicateStackBack()` looks like a better alternative.

Comment: @TristanvO: yes, better than your original, because the existence of `pushToStack` suggests that all stack push's go through this function (and this would be the point where e.g. to add change notifications). However, I would make `pushToStack(int)` call `pushToStack(string)` instead of accessing `stack` directly.   @Evg's suggestion is preferrable **if** duplicating the stack's back is the only forseeable reason where you would push a string.

Comment: And what about having only a `pushToStack(string)` function? I would then call `pushToStack(std::to_string(int))` every time I wanted to push an integer. Is that a good design too? Because I would like to only have one function handling this stuff. @peterchen @Evg

Comment: @TristanvO It's hard to say without seeing the whole solution. I strongly dislike `pushToStack(stack.back());` and would try to find a better alternative.

Comment: I don't see any alternatives anymore. Do you have any ideas? The `void Interpreter::duplicateStackBack()` wouldn't make any sense, since I'm using this duplication only once in this function and nowhere else.

Comment: It really depends on the usage, and whether you're only pushing ints to the stack, and just in a certain case the last value.